Order of sefarim with sections of holier sephorim
Some siddurim have the first three aliyot from every parsha in them. Would such a sidur have any more kedusha and priority in ordering than a normal siddur or even a sefer from Nevi'im?

Note that every Siddur has sections from the Chumash.

I've heard that it's only relevant when dealing with a full sefer of Tanach. How that plays out with siddurim that contain the full Tehillim in the back, I'm not sure....

@ Yehuda Can I add that to the question?
